# Feature Selection + Unpenalized Logistic Regression AUC

Tags: r, logistic, multiple-regression, auc

I am building a predictive model using a highly-dimensional dataset. To reduce dimensionality and reduce overfitting, I used LASSO regression to select features.

```
##Train LASSO model
xdata <-as.matrix(trainingdata[,2:ncol(trainingdata)])
ydata <-as.matrix(trainingdata[,1])
predictors <- names(trainingdata[,-1])
model.formula.string <- paste0('Status~',paste(predictors,sep=' + ',collapse=' + ')
model.formula <- as.formula(model.formula.string)
data <- model.matrix (model.formula,trainingdata)
glmm <- cv.glmnet(x=xdata, y=ydata, family='binomial, alpha=1, type.meaure='auc')

##Extract non-zero
glmm.coef <-coef(glmm,s='lambda.min') #select coefficients with lambda min
glmm.coef.mat <-as.matrix(glmm.coef) #extract coefficiens
predictors.nonzero <- names(glmm.coef.mat[glmm.cef.mat[,1]!=0,]) #select coefficients that dont have a coefficient of zero
```

I used the predictors from the LASSO regression to construct an unpenalized logistic regression model.

```
glm.formula <- paste0('Status ~',paste0(predictors.nonzero, collapse = '+'))
glm.model <- glm (as.formula(glm.formula), data=trainingdata, family='binomial')
```

My question is, how should I calculate the AUC of my final unpenalized logistic regression model?

1 - Run k-fold cross-validation using the formula of the unpenalized logistic regression and use that to calculate the mean AUC and 95% CI

2- Calculate the AUC of the penalized logistic regression model directly using the training dataset

Thank you

Comment: Why run unpenalized logistic regression again?

Comment: This is called the _relaxed lasso_ and is doomed to have poor calibration (absolute predictive accuracy) due to its losing the context, i.e., not inheriting the correct penalization.